# select field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

How I can to pass an array like generated by a controler with the following code:

```
tipos= Type.all
    @listadotipos=[]
    tipos.each do |h|
            @listadotipos.push(h.name)
    end
```

The last code generate an array called @listadotipos. This array is passed to a html.erb view and I want to show all array components inside a Select field in the view.

The select field works this:

```
   <%= f.select :make, options_for_select(["option1", "option2"]) %>
```

How I can do this. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

First of all your controller code can be cleaned up like so:

```
@listadotipos = Type.all.map(&:name)
```

Your view code should work if you use the variable instead of your hard coded array:

```
<%= f.select :make, options_for_select(@listadotipos) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the below code inside the controller :

```
@listadotipos = Type.all.map { |type| [ type.name, type.id ] }
```

You can write as below :

```
<%= f.select :make, @listadotipos %>
```

Read [3.2 Select Boxes for Dealing with Models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-for-dealing-with-models) guide.

Comment: If you're going to build a select which sends a number through it would be better to use the id wouldn't it?  ie `@listadotipos = Type.all.map{|t| [t.name, t.id]}`

Comment: @MaxWilliams Of-course. You are correct. Let me edit it.. Thanks for the useful tips..

Answer (score 0):

Try this in view

```
<%= f.select :make, Type.all.collect(&:name) %>
```

For id

```
<%= f.select :make, Type.all.collect{|type| [type.name, type.id] } %>
```

Comment: ohh yes http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select   :D

Comment: Hehehe.. They did it wrong(I meant not to do calculations in view if you can).. Don't follow the doco so throughly.. :)

Comment: I get an error like this:    undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Comment: this ocurr when I put a validation inside the model

Answer (score 0):

This are the solution. And I dont need code into the controller:

```
<%= f.select :make, options_from_collection_for_select(Type.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Thanks all